# django get_profile error

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to get my userprofile id in the views i have already included below in settings.py

```
 AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'users.UserProfile'
```

views code:

```
def savecontent(request):
 try:
  logging.debug("=========================== in save content")
  logging.debug(dir(request.user))
  my_id = request.user.get_profile().id
  logging.debug(my_id)
```

Error is:

```
 2012-07-17 13:00:00,564 ERROR Error while saing content
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/labs/labs_site/content/views.py", line 21, in savecontent
 my_id = request.user.get_profile().id
 File "/opt/labs/django/django/utils/functional.py", line 185, in inner
 return func(self._wrapped, *args)
 AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'get_profile'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'get_profile'
```

You must have an authenticated user to retrieve a profile, that's your problem

```
@login_required
def foo(request):
    profile_id = request.user.get_profile().id
```

Comment: no - what he means is that the HTTP request must be made by a user who has already been authenticated. Your error output shows that the user is "AnonymousUser" which is what Django uses when the user is *not* authenticated.

Comment: if request.user.is_authenticated(): itself is not passing

Comment: sorry - that does not make sense. do you mean that `request.user.is_authenticated() == False`? If so then that is your problem - you need to log in.

Comment: tbh you shouldn't try to retrieve a profile like that anyway, I have edited my answer for a better routine

Comment: Actually login_required will guarantee that you have authenticated user I simple your view, so no need to check if it exists.