# Django user authentication error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I am using the following code to login, but later when I navigate from `index.html` and try to access the `get_profile()` it says the id is not associated. But when I print the following variables both are false. What am I doing wrong here?

`EDIT`

```
def someotherview(request):
  logging.debug(request.user.is_authenticated()) #prints false
  logging.debug(request.user.is_active) #prints false
```

This is how the login

```
def logon(request):
  qd = get_request_type(request)
  try:
   uname = qd.__getitem__('username')
   pwd = qd.__getitem__('password')

  user = authenticate(username = uname, password = pwd)
  if user is not None:
     response_dict.update({'yes':1})
     logging.debug("labs_home1 ==================")
     return render_to_response('home/index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'response_dict':response_dict,'a':1}))
  else:
     response_dict.update({'yes':0})
     logging.debug("labs_home2 ==================")
     return render_to_response('registration/login.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'response_dict':response_dict,'a':1})
```

Also have a look at my question [django get_profile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523106/django-get-profile-error)

Comment: where does your user come from? Is there a form for login? where do uname and pwd originate from?

Comment: uname and pwd origin from a html template.And the inputs are from a form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`authenticate` only verifies that username and password are correct and returns User instance found for that pair. To actually log user in and have it available in templates, sessions etc you need to call [login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-in)

```
login(request, user)
```

Comment: Yes as u see i did not use the login function..thanks this fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

short answer: use the built-in authentication. Don't try to write youu own. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

- your code is totally broken - in the `login` view the variables `uname` and `pwd` are undefined. please post working code.
- you seem to be doing authentication yourself - why don't you just use the built in authentication methods?
- it looks like part of your problem is that you defining a logged-in user with the variable `user` but that only exists in the scope of the function `logon` - the rest of your code is checking `request.user`. This is why you need to use the built in authentication methods.